# Add to Cart Button Product Qty

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using magento 1.9

In default theme when i Add 4 qty of product although total qty is 3. this error msg shows on product page "The requested quantity is not available."

But in Jumbo theme Error msg not showing on product page.

how to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

Check whether any other Success/ Error/ Waring messages displaying in your Jumbo theme.

If no messages are displaying, in the sense.
Just check with the following steps.

1) Check your page.xml

```
app/design/frontend/`<your_pakg>/<your_theme>`/layout/page.xml
```

inside

```
<block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/3columns.phtml">
...
...
    //Check this line exist, if not add this
    <block type="core/messages" name="global_messages" as="global_messages"/>
...
...
</block>
```

2) And then check your phtml file.
app/design/frontend/`<your_pakg>/<your_theme>`/template/page/3columns.phtml

```
<div class="col-main">
...
...
    //Check this line exist, if not add this
     <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
...
...
</div>
```